# Getting new emails on exchange server with SDK

Tags: sdk, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

We recently found out using the outlook object in C# will not work for our requirements.
Therefor we are looking to program something on the exchange server itself using (maybe) one of the exchange SDK's ...

Since i have no knowledge about these sdk's or even exchange server i'm looking for some help here.

I need something that writes the flatspaceurl (or something that i can match with the flatspaceurl)  , subject , senddate and sender   to a file at the very moment a mail comes in for a particular mailbox (info@blabla.be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Exchange 2010, you don't use the flatspace url.. it is a WebDAV thing.

Use the Exchange Managed API ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)).

You can store the ItemId in the data for future reference. It is stable unless the mail is moved to another folder on the mailbox.

To monitor a folder for new mails, you can use Push, pull or streaming notifications.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa579617(v=exchg.140).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa579617%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg236898(v=EXCHG.140).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg236898%28v=EXCHG.140%29.aspx)

http://exchangenotification.codeplex.com/

Comment: So using exchange SDK or managed API will still force me to use webservices, will still be incorrect if a user moves a mail to another folder and has no flatspaceurl ?  

I might as wel use the outlook object since this does all the webservice work for me ?????,

Comment: Hi, the flatspace url also changes when a mail is moved into another folder, because it contains the EntryId of the folder. To get a static identifier, you can either attach a custom property (http://www.infinitec.de/post/2009/03/27/Saving-custom-data-on-Exchange-elements-with-The-Exchange-WebServices.aspx) or use one of the existing ID properties (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc815908.aspx).

Comment: Ok thx, but my main question is:  Does the outlook object provide equal functionality as the AWS SDK in terms of data correctness?   Since it's incorrect in both options when a email is moved to another folder and outlook probably uses the same webservices i see no use in using the SDK ?

Comment: The EntryIds generated by Outlook are equally unstable. The difference between the two object models is that using the EWS sdk you talk directly with the server. It's more suited for service applications. Outlook doesn't work well in these situations.